# Why am I earning rep from this answer?

Tags: support

I'm confused here. I have an answer to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172527/how-to-make-obsidian-without-lava-in-minecraft-pocket-edition-ipad-tablet) question here, and strangely enough, I'm earning reputation from it even though it hasn't been upvoted or accepted. Why? I not complaining or anything, but I don't think it's right for me to be earning glitched reputation while everyone else earns their reputation legitimately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer *has* been upvoted. Once. Awarding you +10 rep.

Your answer has *also* been downvoted. Once. Docking you -2 rep.

So, you've gained a net 8 reputation, and your answer has a net score of 0.

Once you've reached 1,000 reputation, you'll be able to click on the score of a post to see the exact vote totals that produce a net score like this for yourself.

Comment: I see, I as just confused because it read as zero votes, so I was unaware that votes had taken place.

Comment: Related: http://stackapps.com/q/3082/24578